# Jquery Animating between colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fairly rudimentary question. If I have a random number variable which picks a random selection out of an array for example "red" I want to be able to store that as the current color whilst it picks a new colour after 5 seconds and then animate from the current colour "red" to the new colours for example "green" so it fades the background or body of the document slowly from one to the other.

I have some code that I have written so far but I am unsure how I would get this, I know I would have to store the current color if it was found then find the next color but Im not sure how.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Roger</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Roger.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Roger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>

<script>

var Colours = [];
var randCol;
var curCol;

Colours[0] = "red";
Colours[1] = "green";
Colours[2] = "blue";
Colours[3] = "black";
Colours[4] = "grey";

window.setInterval(function(){
 randCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 0

alert(randCol);

var nextCol= Colours[randCol];

    if(Colours[randCol] == Colours[0]) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
 curCol = "red"; 
    }
    else if(Colours[randCol] == Colours[1]) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"; 
  curCol = "green"; 

    }
    else if(Colours[randCol] == Colours[2]) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  curCol = "green"; 

    }
    else if(Colours[randCol] == Colours[3]) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"; 
  curCol = "black"; 

    }
    else if(Colours[randCol] == Colours[4]) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="grey";
  curCol = "grey"; 

    }


}, 5000);



</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you just place the script outside the body tags ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what this has to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something more like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Roger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Roger.css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Roger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- end .container -->
        </div>
        <script>
            var Colours = [
                "red",
                "green",
                "blue",
                "black",
                "grey"
            ],
                prevCol = null;


            window.setInterval(function () {
                var randCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * Colours.length)
                while (randCol === prevCol) randCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
                prevCol = randCol;
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = Colours[randCol];
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CEYRV/)

To animate colors with jQuery you'll need a plugin, it that's what you're going to next ?

Comment: That looks a lot more tidy thanks! Yeh that was the aim of my question to try and animate between those colours. I was under the impression jquery was able to animate between colours?? Is that not the case?

Comment: @DanKristianWilliams `$('body').animate({
    backgroundColor: Colours[randCol]
});` and include any plugin which support color animation as jQuery color or even UI.

Comment: ^^ What he said, jQuery UI supports color animation, jQuery does not unless you add the UI library or another plugin, as the UI library is rather large and it doesn't make sense to add it just to animate some colors, a plugin is usually preferred, here's a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/CEYRV/1/

Comment: Aha that works nicely. Am I right in saying that prevCol holds the last colour that was set? I will be using it to dynamically change the background colour. So if a value that I get is below 5 it will go from the last background set to the new colour. At the moment I wanted to do it with a random number just to test it.

Comment: Yes, I used the prevCol variable to hold the "previous" color outside the loop to compare against the current color so the same color doesn't come twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

To do the fading from one color to the other without additional plugins, you could set the start background color to the `body`, the end background color to the `.container` and then incrementally change the opacity of the `.container` from 0 (transparent) to 1 (visible) using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` function.